# Nginx proxy_pass from route without trailing slash

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-config

I would like to configure Nginx to have one route on my domain proxy to another URL. More specifically, I'd like `my.domain.com/special_route` to proxy to `another.domain.com` and for the URL to remain unchanged in the address bar. For example, I'd like `my.domain.com/special_route/some_path` to proxy to `another.domain.com/some_path`, while the URL remains unchanged.

This is the configuration I have added so far:

```
  set $another_url https://another.domain.com;
  
  location ~ /special_route(/?.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

    proxy_pass $another_url$1;
  }
```

It appears to work mostly as intended with one notable exception. `my.domain.com/special_route/some_path` works, `my.domain.com/special_route/` also works. However, `my.domain.com/special_route` (without the trailing slash) does not work. It appears to proxy to `another.domain.com/special_route`.

What do I need to change or add to my config to get the base route working without the trailing slash?

Answer (score 2):

When the `$1` is empty, it becomes just `proxy_pass http://upstream` which means the url is passed in full to the backend (`/special_route`).

The variable need to be updated to `/` in such cases. This is one possible method:

```
# tip: it should start with ^/ unless you do mean
# to allow accessing /thing/special_route in the same fashion
location ~ ^/special_route(/?.*)$ {
  proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
  # another tip: unless you know what you're doing,
  # don't use $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for. Just use $remote_addr
  # otherwise people may be able to fake their ip in some cases
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;

  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

  set $proxy_url $1;
  if ($proxy_url = '') {
    set $proxy_url /;
  }
  proxy_pass $another_url$proxy_url;
}
```